# Why does std::lower_bound with greater-than compare function give no match?

Tags: c++

Let's look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> exmpl = { 2, 3, 6, 9, 134, 1143, 2345 };

    auto LessThan     = [](const int a, const int b) -> bool { return a < b; };
    auto GreaterThan  = [](const int a, const int b) -> bool { return a > b; };

    auto it_reverse_less_than    = std::lower_bound(exmpl.rbegin(), exmpl.rend(), 8, LessThan);
    auto it_reverse_greater_than = std::lower_bound(exmpl.rbegin(), exmpl.rend(), 8, GreaterThan);

    auto it_forward_less_than    = std::lower_bound(exmpl.begin(),  exmpl.end(), 8, LessThan);
    auto it_forward_greater_than = std::lower_bound(exmpl.begin(),  exmpl.end(), 8, GreaterThan);

    std::cout << *it_reverse_less_than << "\n";
    std::cout << *it_reverse_greater_than << "\n";
    std::cout << *it_forward_less_than << "\n";
    std::cout << (it_forward_greater_than == exmpl.end());

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
2345
6
9
1
```

I've checked the results using VC++ compiler as well as gcc via Ideone (see the link below) and they are the same.

I think `it_reverse_greater_than` points to `1143` as it is the first element that the reverse iterator sees for which the compare function returns `false`. I don't understand though why the `GreaterThan` function doesn't return a match when used with forward iterators (`it_forward_greater_than` points to `end()`). Shouldn't `it_forward_greater_than` point to `2` as it is the first element for which the compare function returns `false`? Isn't it an analogical situation to `it_reverse_greater_than` pointing to the last element, i.e. the first one that the reverse iterator sees?

Here is the code in Ideone:
https://ideone.com/0z55ss

Comment: `std::lower_bound` expects that the range is sorted according to the predicate given. You pass a range that is not thus sorted. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed the code. Originally the vector was sorted and it is now.

Comment: The vector is sorted, but not according to each predicate. Different predicates require differently sorted vectors.

Comment: Ok, but why does the reverse iterator approach work then? As far as I understand, it's not sorted from the reverse iterator's point of view either.

Comment: Two out of four calls are correct. The other two exhibit undefined behavior as the range is ordered the wrong way round.

Comment: So what might be the reason that the two different compilers give the same results? Coincidence or is that something else?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. It is uninteresting to analyse an outcome of a program that exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @KjMag The reason is that you have undefined behavior. Having undefined behavior can potentially explain any behavior. There is little to gain from trying to understand why undefined behavior produces a specific behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys for the quick answers. I wasn't sure if it's undefined behaviour or some subtlety about the rules regarding how lower_bound works that I just don't get.

Comment: Just to be clear: the other undefined behaviour refers to it_reverse_less_than, right?

Comment: What the point to use greater than in this context?

Comment: @Slava It depends which context you ask about. In case of reverse iterator it makes sense. In case of forward iterator - I was just surprised that reverse iterator with less than compare function worked and wanted to check whether forward iterator with greater than would work similarly. When I saw the result, I've decided to ask this question to make sure what's going on.

Comment: 'In case of reverse iterator it makes sense.' No it does not. Question is why do you need to search in sorted container using different predicate? Or what the point to call `std::lower_bound` with different predicate? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Slava I have a large vector and need a small chunk of it limited by lower and upper bound. In each iteration the lower bound changes and gets a little closer to the beginning of the vector, so I can either search the whole vector for the boundary values each time, or I can save iterators pointing to the previous boundary points and start searching new ones starting from them. To find the lower bound using the previously found iterator, I need to go through the vector backwards, and std::lower_bound's default predicate won't work with reverse iterators.